# Spring Boot - How To Serve Angular2 Compiled Files

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I have a restful server done with Spring Boot and for front-end i have an application created by Angular2. I have been trying to put frontend files on tomcat so that i wont need to serve them separately however i couldn't manage that.

I have the files in /dist folder from Angular2 front-end project. But no matter where i place it, Spring wouldn't serve them. How can manage to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to put it  `src/main/resources/static/`.

Refer, https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot for more on this.

I have an spring boot and angular 2 project put in same codebase for experiment. Please use this as example.

https://github.com/reflexdemon/shop

Comment: I put them in static folder but index.html doesn't fire up. My file structure is : 
http://i.imgur.com/XrJsnBS.png


And in my HomeController i have mapped the url "/" and it returns "home".
But still i am getting the following:

15:00:03.675 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/zift/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: Can you please let me know your tree structure on the `static` folder?

Comment: how are you starting the spring boot application?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't print properly on the comment

```
static
├── index.html
├── inline.bundle.js
├── inline.bundle.js.map
├── main.bundle.js
├── main.bundle.js.map
├── styles.bundle.js
├── styles.bundle.js.map
├── vendor.bundle.js
└── vendor.bundle.js.map
```