# Running compiled Angular screens inside spring boot as well as jersey backend

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I've spent quite a bit of time struggling with getting spring boot to serve up my angular screens, while also serving our back end.  I will admit that I'm pretty new to the spring/jersey realm so I may not be asking the right questions or searching he right thing.

Similar to this post [Spring Boot - How To Serve Angular2 Compiled Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719654/spring-boot-how-to-serve-angular2-compiled-files) I have a few compiled angular screens, as well as some rest end points that I want to run inside of a single jar file.  I have tried the example posted in that SO article, but no luck.

I can get a single index.html file to work as long as I don't include my JerseyConfig class

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

   public JerseyConfig() {
      register(WorkflowManagementResourceV1_0.class);
   }
}
```

But when I remove the JerseyConfig, my endpoints no longer are enabled.

I also have never managed to get the compiled Angular screen to come up inside of spring either.

I have tried putting things in  resources/static, resources/public/ webapps/resources etc.

I will happyily add more content and detail, but first I'm curious if this is still possible (I assume it is).  And second is there some sort of configuration, pom dependency, or auto config that needs to be done to enable this?

I've also tried adding the @Controller to my main application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you building the frontend with `ng-cli`?

Comment: I'm actually using a github project so I can build it with maven
https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Comment: Please add the `frontend-maven-plugin` build configuration from `pom.xml`

Comment: From the spring boot project or the one that builds and compiles my angular

Comment: Currently I'm running this compiled screen inside of wildfly

Comment: The one used when you call `mvn package`

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow. For now I'm just putting the compiled screen in a folder under resources/static.  I can see that these files are built into the jar file, but not sure how I would access them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166006/discussion-between-the-head-rush-and-gr-envoy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found the following article very useful:

https://www.geekmj.org/jersey/spring-boot-jersey-static-web-files-support-403/

Basically, Jersey is taking over all the requests. The method described in the article is to configure Jersey to forward 404's. Since the request to your static content is a 404 to Jersey, it will forward it on and it will be handled automatically by the underlying system.

Add the Spring web dependency if you do not already have it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In application.properties, configure a Jersey filter:

```
spring.jersey.type=filter
```

And finally, configure Jersey to forward 404's in your JerseyConfig:

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

   public JerseyConfig() {
       register(WorkflowManagementResourceV1_0.class);

       // set jersey to pass 404's to the underlying system (this makes the screens work)
       property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
   }
}
```

After all that, your static content should be available!

Comment: Thanks!  It took a little bit of playing but this was pretty much exactly what I needed to get it working

Comment: Thanks. I have migrated a jersey standalone + angular app to spring boot. I ran into the above problem that jersey config was filtering my screens and your fix really helped.